# Convert Utc date time to web user's local date time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a .NET web site that captures a C# `DateTime` value and stores it in database with UTC value. Upon showing that datetime value on web page, what I want is that date time UTC value to be converted to web user's local time zone properly. *So web users in different time zones will see the displayed date time value with different date time results.*

I have 2 following approaches. I do not know which is the best and correct one.

**Approach 1:** Let C# server side codes to convert the UTC `DateTime` value to local date time using .NET library method `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` and pass that converted value to client side to display without any further client side codes.

**Approach 2:** I do not do any time conversion using C# server side codes. Instead, I simply pass the UTC datetime value to client side and I will use some client side (javaScript or some JS library) codes to do the conversion before displaying it to web user.

*Question 1:* Approach 1 or Approach 2 is the best and correct one?

*Question 2:* The .NET library `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` method will convert a datetime value to local time of web user; web server's local time; OR web user's computer OS time?

*Question 3:* How can I test my web page with different time zones to see the best/correct approach working?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In most language runtimes (I can't say for sure that C# is like this, but I'd be surprised if it were not), the core of a date-time value is an offset in seconds or milliseconds from a specific UTC date-time "epoch" value. JavaScript is no different. If you pass that offset to create a JavaScript Date instance, then using the JavaScript APIs to get date parts or to create a formatted string will (unless you use the UTC APIs) give you local time at the client.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that all date/times be stored in UTC on the server and that, in your case, you do the web client timezone conversion on the client side. I suggest the [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) library for client-side operations. If you use Moment, look at the [guess() method](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) for determining the client's current timezone.

By the way, you might want to determine the client's current timezone periodically in case 1) the user in on a mobile device and physically moves to another timezone or, 2) the user's session lasts long enough to transition from Daylight Savings Time (DST) to Standard Time (STD) or *vice versa*.

Now, I said "in you case" because, based on your question you don't seem to need to worry about calculating time intervals between 2 date/times. If you need to do that you also have to consider the complication of changes in a timezone from 3 sources:

1. Changing from STD to DST (and *vice versa*) that occurs twice a year in many timezones.
2. Changes to the UTC offset of a timezone that sometimes happens when a government implements a change.
3. Changes to the date/time when a location converts from STD to DST or *vice versa*.

Also, you might need to consider the complication of dealing with the potential for a local time corresponding to two UTC times! This can happen when a local time for a location falls within the 1 hour preceeding the date/time when that location converts from DST to STD. That 1 hour period is *repeated* when a 'fallback' from DST to STD time occurs and so you need to resolve which of 2 possible UTC times you want to store in your database.

If any of the above timezone complications might exist for you, consider storing a *location* along with the date/time since this context is required for timezone calculations. The location can be lat/lon which you would need to map to a timezone or you could keep it simple and store just the timezone. Lat/lon is sometimes more desirable since sometimes governments decide to move a location into a new timezone (but this is pretty rare).